# INSERT INTO from two tables into one empty table with foreign key constraints

Tags: sql

I have a table called PurchaseOrderAccount that is empty. I need to insert the Account code from a table called DailyCosts. Also, I need to Insert a PurchaseOrderID from PurchaseOrder.ID. These are both foreign key restraints. No columns will accept Null. This is what I have:

```
   Insert Into PurchaseOrderAccount (WellID, JobID,ID,PurchaseOrderID,AccountCode)
    Select  DailyCosts.WellID, 
            DailyCosts.JobID,
            NEWID(),
            PurchaseOrder.ID,
            DailyCosts.AccountCode 
    From DailyCosts 
    inner join
         PurchaseOrder 
       on DailyCosts.Notes =PurchaseOrder.PONumber 
    Join 
         PurchaseOrderDailyCost 
       On DailyCosts.DailyCostID = PurchaseOrderDailyCost.DailyCostID 
   Where DailyCosts.WellID = '24A-23' 
   Group By DailyCosts.WellID, 
            DailyCosts.JobID,
            PurchaseOrder.ID,
            DailyCosts.AccountCode;
```

With this, I get 191 records. I only want unique AccountCodes from DailyCosts which are 54. I would appreciate any direction.

Comment: Please post sample input/output.

Comment: Please share your table structure and sample data you want to insert in new table

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you would have to remove DailyCosts.JobID in the 'Group By' if you want all unique combinations of DailyCosts.AccountCode and PurchaseOrder.ID.

As you have filtered DailyCosts.WellID = '24A-23', a group by should not affect it.

```
  Insert Into PurchaseOrderAccount (WellID, ID,PurchaseOrderID,AccountCode)
    Select  DailyCosts.WellID, 
            NEWID(),
            PurchaseOrder.ID,
            DailyCosts.AccountCode 
    From DailyCosts 
    inner join
         PurchaseOrder 
       on DailyCosts.Notes =PurchaseOrder.PONumber 
    Join 
         PurchaseOrderDailyCost 
       On DailyCosts.DailyCostID = PurchaseOrderDailyCost.DailyCostID 
   Where DailyCosts.WellID = '24A-23' 
   Group By DailyCosts.WellID, 
            PurchaseOrder.ID,
            DailyCosts.AccountCode;
```

Here, I believe that there would be multiple JobID's causing your total number to be coming to 191, instead of the expected 41. Please let me know if this works for you.